# Using a macro to create numerous similar macros in word

Tags: ms-word, macros

I am trying to streamline the process of creating a number of virtually identical macros in word and wondering if there is way to use a macro to do it!

What I want:
I have a macro to create a comment with predetermined text on some selected text in a word document.  I need to make a number of these with different texts in each of them and each having their own separate button.  So, what I want is a separate macro button that brings up a dialogue box that creates these buttons and allows me to fill in the following three variables:

1. The name (and display name?) of the newly created macro
2. The tab placement of that macro under a specific tab under a specific group on the ribbon (I want to be able to enter the tab but the group will be the same each time).
3. The text to be entered into the comment box in the new macro

In case it matters, the current macro I am using for the comment boxes is as follows (note some of this was used to auto-close the reviewing pane which kept opening when using the comment macro):

```
Dim n As Long
n = ActiveWindow.Panes.Count

'Adds Comment and text
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
Selection.TypeText Text:="comment text here"

'Auto-closes Reviewing Pane
With ActiveWindow
If .Panes.Count = n + 1 Then
.Panes(n + 1).Close

End If
End With
End Sub
```

Any and all help is appreciated!!!  Thank you.